# Dataflow job not running after worker started?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

Sometimes GCP dataflow jobs not starting after submitting even after workers are started successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the possible cause for not starting a dataflow job:

1) Not having enough permission for `service account` or `IAM user`

- Add `dataflow admin` permission to a service account.
- For IAM user add broad level access such as `EDITOR` or `OWNER` then run below command

  - `gcloud config set project <your_project_id>`
  - `gcloud auth login`
  - `gcloud auth login application-default`

2) Sometimes package dependency can cause this. To resolve it, perform the below steps:
Generate `setup.py` from your local `requirements.txt`

```
- pip freeze > requirements.txt
- then add packages from `requirements.txt` into `setup.py`
- Add proper path of `setup.py` in JOB CONFIG.
```